# Network issues after upgrading to Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: networking, server, 18.04, minidlna

I'm having some network issues after I've upgraded from Ubuntu 16.04 to 18.04. 
Internet works fine, but some services as minidlna or clementine remote do not work.

The thing is that I took a look to minidlna log file and all seems to work fine, only that dlna server is not registered anymore in the network so I suspect some changes in 18.04, but I can't figure out what.

Firewall (ufw) is disabled. Any clues please?

Thanks

Comment: you should change the question to reflect more precisely your problem: "minidlna not working after upgrading to ubuntu 18.04"

Comment: Well, there are many services not working properly (today I've had problems also with transmission) not only minidlna so I prefer to let it as is. Thank you anyway @TomášPospíšek

Comment: yes, but the problem is that (I'm paraphrasing here!) if you say "there are many things not working here, can somebody please tell me the solution to those problems" then that question is too wide. You need to solve one problem at a time.

Comment: What I meant is that all these services down were the symptoms of a network management problem not a specific software problem.